# Converting all capital words to camel case in vim

Tags: vim

Is there a way to turn a word like `EXPIRATIONDATE` to `ExpirationDate` in Vim? I have around 100 automatically generated variables that are all uppercase and I would like them to be in camel case. I can't control the generation output. I'm hoping there is a macro for this in Vim but I'm pretty certain I'll have to do it by hand.

Comment: I can't imagine this being something that can be easily automated with any kind of accuracy.  How would it know when one word ends and another starts?

Comment: I understand it’s difficult. I wasn’t expecting there to be an answer, but there are a lot of people that are smarter than me. The answer is always no if you don’t ask. The only thing I can think of is searching through a dictionary and when finding a match in a word, capitalize accordingly. It would be imperfect, but might catch enough to make doing it by hand not suck. However, that’s more work than just doing it by hand. Thank you for commenting anyway.

Comment: Yeah, the problem I see is you would have to use a dictionary to compare everything against, and there'd be cases where a decision would have to be made such as, is `PINEAPPLE` `Pineapple`, or `PineApple`?  We might then be getting into machine learning territory to try to guess which one is intended.  At that point... may as well do it all by hand.  To get started, you could probably use a macro to make all but the first letter lowercase and then you'd just have to go through and manually capitalize the first letters of the interior words.  Won't automate the job, but might make it easier.

Comment: Good thought. I will do that.

Comment: Your example doesn't even contain English words, so you won't be able to use an English dictionary to parse your variables.

Comment: No, that's just my lack of spelling. I changed the name when I copied it over and failed.

Comment: If the generated names are built from a small number of base words, it's probably doable with a regex substitution (or several successive ones, whichever you find more convenient).

Comment: If you had `EXPIRATION_DATE`, [abolish.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish#coercion) by Tim Pope could convert it into `ExpirationDate` with `crm` (`:help cr`). For reasons above, with `EXPIRATIONDATE`, you're on your own.